# how to know if a json object contains a json object

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am a novice in java and I am looking for a way to know if a json object contains another jsonObject by using json.org library  (not json.org.simple).

For the moment I am using this :

```
JSONObject json= new JSONObject();
json.has("JsonFieldName");
```

but but I need to know if there is a way to not specify the Json field Name

If you have a better solution with Json.org, I will take.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an `Iterator` for all the keys in the object from [`keys`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()), and loop through them seeing if any of the values for the keys is a `JSONObject` (as opposed to a `JSONArray` or primitive).

```
for (String key : json.keys()) {
    if (json.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
        // Yes, it contains at least one JSONObject, whose key is `key`
    }
}
```